# I need to center the <div> in <td>

Tags: html, css

I need to center the `<div>` in `<td>` because now (with my code) I see the div at right but I want to see the div in the center of `<td>`. This is my code:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>Start date</label>
          <br/>
          <input type="date" name="start_date">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>End date</label>
          <br/>
          <input type="date" name="end_date">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyone can help me? I don' know how I can do this.

Comment: You really should not use tables for layouts, there are better solutions. You have vertical-align and text-align, margins etc

Comment: If you are really bound to use `td` you can use `<td style='text-align:center'>`

Comment: `text-align: center;` only centers the text, not the `div`.

Comment: what your want to ??

Answer (score 22):

You can only center the `div` (*not the text!*) without using javascript by adding a `width` to the elements. Then you can use `margin: auto;`.

```css
div { 
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto; 
}
```

```html
  <table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>Start date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="start_date">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>End date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="end_date">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another way would be to use jQuery. This can even work with dynamic width.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("td div").each(function() {
        var element = $(this),
            elementWidth = element.width(),
            parentWidth = element.parent().width();

        element.css("margin-left", ((parentWidth - elementWidth) / 2) + "px");
    });
}).resize();
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>Start date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="start_date">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>End date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="end_date">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 19):

If you do not force the width set for `div`, changes in alignment for `td` do nothing because `div` takes 100% of the width `td`. Then you need to provide alignment for the `div` **NOT** using text-align:

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

let `div` leveled at you and its width is less than the width so on. then use `margin`:

```
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is better use flex:

```
td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea! Way better as the `text-align` only answers around here! +1

Comment: I think this is the best answer overall. In my case the td is auto-generated (by datatables) so I couldn't easily do stuff like <td align=center>. Margin auto for the win.

Comment: display flex breaks the layout of my table. Maybe better to add another div inside the td and center using that.

Answer (score 6):

Use `align` in `td`

```
<td align='center'>
```

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/safocp91/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="text-align: center;"` in the table tag. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuoo8mqa/1/)

```
<table width="100%" style="text-align: center;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <label>Start date</label><br/>
                <input type="date" name="start_date">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <label>End date</label><br/>
                <input type="date" name="end_date">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are so many upvotes here? The question is about to center a `div` in a `td`. This answer will only center the text inside, ignoring the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Set this to the `div`:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: I tried this however it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieved something like this

```html
 <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div>
                        <label>Start date</label><br/>
                        <input type="date" name="start_date">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div>
                        <label>End date</label><br/>
                        <input type="date" name="end_date">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want everything inside the div to center on the page. Try:

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

or

```
style="justify-content:center;"
```

Comment: `justify-content:center;` I don't see any element wird `displae: flex;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the content of your div with:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
```

but you should really put that in your CSS file and not inline

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>Start date</label>
          <br/>
          <input type="date" name="start_date">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <div>
          <label>End date</label>
          <br/>
          <input type="date" name="end_date">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align: center;` into your div tags

```
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <label>Start date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="start_date">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <label>End date</label><br/>
          <input type="date" name="end_date">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an interesting case where none of these solutions worked. There's a CSS level 3 trick that involves **top:50%** that DID work for me: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.tmpl#vertical3

**The case I'm dealing with:**
A jQuery slideshow that outputs divs. The site is adaptive, so I can't put in fixed widths for any of the elements. Despite that, I wanted to center items both vertically and horizontally inside each slide.

**1. Using *text-align:center* wasn't enough** because I also wanted to vertically center the text. Only table-cell elements react to *vertical-align:middle*. Which I think is a shame, because table-cell elements have a lot of, lets say... luggage. See point 2.

**2. Declaring the inner div with *display:table-cell* didn't work** because while I could center the text both horizontally and vertically *inside* the table-cell, the table-cell remained glued to the left inside its parent div.
The table-cell element did not react to *width:100%* or *margin:0 auto*. Nor did it obey the *text-align:center* of the parent div.

**3. The *top:50%* hack (if I may call it that) does work** if you follow the rules from the linked article. It places the element 50% down the height of the parent element and uses *translate* to move the child element back upwards by half its own height.
The catch is that it probably won't work on old browsers.

**Aren't you screwed anyway trying to vertically align something in a fluid width design?** Yes, for this trick to work the parent element must have a fixed height. Will take some experimenting.

**Dude, this discussion is about horizontal alignment.** Yes, I understand. But when you're desperate for a weird solution to a weird problem, a thread like this can be a life saver. Besides, this trick also works horizontally.